# service mysql start failed on ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, service, mysql5

Here is my dilemma (somehow similar to [this resource](https://serverfault.com/questions/165537/how-to-restore-my-mysql-5-1-on-ubuntu-10-4) and I tried everything, but nothing helped):

```
root@vuxomys01:~# service mysql status
mysql start/running
```

When I'm looking for the process:

```
root@vuxomys01:~# ps ax | grep mysql
2263 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto mysql
```

I checked the logs and `/var/log/mysql/error.log` is empty, but there is weird stuff in `/var/log/syslog` ...

```
root@vuxomys01:~# grep mysql /var/log/syslog
...
Dec  8 15:24:17 vuxomys01 init: mysql post-start process (1963) terminated with status 1
Dec  8 15:24:17 vuxomys01 kernel: [  460.182640] type=1505 audit(1323375857.580:28):  operation="profile_replace" pid=2098 name="/usr/sbin/mysqld"
Dec  8 15:24:17 vuxomys01 init: mysql main process (2102) terminated with status 1
Dec  8 15:24:17 vuxomys01 init: mysql main process ended, respawning
Dec  8 15:24:47 vuxomys01 init: mysql post-start process (2103) terminated with status 1
```

... and `/var/log/daemon.log`

```
root@vuxomys01:~# grep mysql /var/log/daemon.log
...
Dec  8 15:24:17 vuxomys01 init: mysql post-start process (1963) terminated with status 1
Dec  8 15:24:17 vuxomys01 init: mysql main process (2102) terminated with status 1
Dec  8 15:24:17 vuxomys01 init: mysql main process ended, respawning
Dec  8 15:24:47 vuxomys01 init: mysql post-start process (2103) terminated with status 1
```

Any other ideas would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance!

- Eugene.

Comment: Can you please list the distro, version and how mysql was installed

Comment: This question should be migrated to serverfault.

Comment: Unbe-f...-livable! It was a problem of my.cnf, which was missing an "h" in "character_set_server = utf8" :( Anyway, thanks for intention!

Comment: So, please mark your question as solved / closed

Answer (score 1):

I think you have an infinite loop in the post-start script due to an incomplete migration of MySQL. Check this [thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1475798), i'm sure the solution is there.

Comment: check this place :

http://askubuntu.com/questions/127264/cant-start-mysql-mysql-respawning-too-fast-stopped#


"Can't start mysql - mysql respawning too fast, stopped"

Comment: For the google spawn: My issue was I forgot to chown/chmod the files I moved over from another server during a migration.  Once things had the proper owner and permissions mysql started up directly.